# Find common objects in N lists

Tags: c#

I have N lists of "People".  People have 2 properties: `Id` and `Name`. I want to find the People that are contained in all N lists. I only want to match on the Id.

Below is my starting point:

```
List<People> result = new List<People>();

//I think I only need to find items in the first list that are in the others
foreach (People person in peoplesList.First()) {

    //then this is the start of iterating through the other full lists
    foreach (List<People> list in peoplesList.Skip(1)) {

        //Do I even need this?

    }
}
```

I am stuck trying to wrap my head around the middle part. I only want ones that are in each list from `peoplesList.Skip(1)`.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematically speaking; you are looking for the set intersection between all of your lists. Luckily, LINQ has an `Instersect` method, so you can iteratively intersect your sets.

```
List<List<People>> lists; //Initialize with your data
IEnumerable<People> commonPeople = lists.First();
foreach (List<People> list in lists.Skip(1))
{
   commonPeople = commonPeople.Intersect(list);
}
//commonPeople is now an IEnumerable containing the intersection of all lists
```

To get the "ID" selector working you will need to implement `IEqualityComparer` for `People`

```
IEqualityComparer<People> comparer = new PeopleComparer();
...
commonPeople = commonPeople.Intersect(list, comparer);
```

Actual implementation of `IEqualityComparer` left out since its pretty darn simple.

Comment: Ah so we just keep making a change to the existing list w/ each intersection.  Nice!  Thanks, I will give this a shot

Comment: @DustinBreakey Not a new `List` (though you *could* do that, just more inefficient) a new `IEnumerable` so you only execute the full query when you iterate `commonPeople` at the end.