# Rank (top 3) the User that most occur in N lists?

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin

So, I have a List of N Images and each image I have a List that interacted. I need to Rank the user that most interact within Images (List).
Searching at stack i saw something about Intersect with LINQ, but is not what i need.

I am starting with development...so, i don´t know too much about LINQ

Comment: can we see the some LINQ ..which you have tried ??

Comment: @RohitasBehera i was looking and tried based at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705782/find-common-objects-in-n-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image object has a property `Users` which is a `List` of the users that interacted with it, then you can use `SelectMany` on your list of images to take the lists of users for each image and flatten them into a single list:

```
listOfImages.SelectMany(image => image.Users)
```

This won't remove duplicates, so each user will appear once for each time they interacted with an image. You can then use `GroupBy` to group up 'duplicate' users into groups; the size of each group will be the number of times that user appears in the flattened list:

```
listOfImages.SelectMany(image => image.Users)
            .GroupBy(user => user)
```

Then since you want the top three, use `OrderByDescending` to rank them by the number of times they appear, and `Take(3)` to then take the top three. Then you'll need to use `Select` to return a list of users, since `GroupBy` returns a generic type `IGrouping`. `FirstOrDefault()` returns the first item in each group, which is going to be a user, or `null` if the group is empty.

```
listOfImages.SelectMany(image => image.Users)
            .GroupBy(user => user)
            .OrderByDescending(group => group.Count())
            .Take(3)
            .Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault())
```

This should hopefully achieve what you want. I suggest you read up on LINQ so you understand how all its methods work - it's pretty useful once you know how to use it. Play around with it a bit so you get a feel for it - some methods like `OrderBy` and `Take` are pretty self-explanatory, others like `SelectMany` aren't quite so obvious.

Comment: Thanks...i never saw a better explanation. I am trying to adapt to my case...
In my case, I have a list<string> that are the ID´s of Images...
Then, for each ID image i get a list<Users> that interacted...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this with linq will do the job

```
 public class User
    {
        public User(int id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Image
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
.......

     public List<Tuple<int, int>> OrderByUser(IList<Image> cursos)
            {
                 var data = cursos.SelectMany(x => x.Users
                .Select(p => new { image = x, user = p }))
                .GroupBy(x => x.user.Id)
                .Select(x => new { userId = x.Key, total = x.Count() })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.total)
                .Take(3);
            data = data.OrderByDescending(x => x.total);
            return data.Select(x=> new Tuple<int, int>(x.userId, x.total)).ToList();
            }
```

Comment: While this is basically the same as my answer, I feel like this is more confusing than it needs to be. The `Select` clause inside the `SelectMany` is wholly unnecessary since you never use the `image` member of your anonymous type. The second `Select` is superfluous as well, as is the second `OrderByDescending`. And I'm not personally sure on the `Tuple`, but that may just be me.